# trying to append html, but function keeps wiping "genre" when I want to add "subgenre"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to use the .append to add a second level (breadcrumb) to a  tag dynamically inserted into a page.

Here is the current behavior, when I click on a genre in the menu the books appear in the dynamic div.  It then shows "recommend in" followed by the level 1 span + the name of the genre.

When I click on a subgenre, the genre is removed completely and the subgenre added in with the "/"

So instead of seeing "Recommended In Genre / Subgenre"

I'm just getting "Recommended in / Subgenre"

I think something in this function is wiping it.  Any hints you could give me would be great.

```
$("#genreList a").click( function(event){
    $("#genreList a").removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);

    if ( self.attr('data-link') !== undefined ) {
        slideGenreList(self.attr('data-link'), self.attr('data-title'), $('#' + self.attr('data-link')));
    }

    // Draw and display the selected genre or the regular page if all genres is selected
    if ( self.attr('data-link') == 'all_genres' ) {
        $('#genreContainer .dynamic').hide();
        $('#genreContainer .default').fadeIn();
        //$('.breadcrumb').html('Genres');

    }
    else {
        $('#genreContainer .default').hide();
        $('#genreContainer .dynamic').html( '<h3 class="no-margin-top breadcrumb">Recommended in' + ' <a href="' + self.attr('href') + '" class="button right">See All</a></h3><div class="genre no-margin-top" data-context="/genreList/' + self.attr('data-genreId') + '"></div>').fadeIn();
        if (self.parents('ul#all_genres').length > 0) {
                $('.breadcrumb .level1').remove();
                $('.breadcrumb').append('<span class="level1 black">  ' + self.attr('data-title') + '</span>');
            } else {
                $('.breadcrumb .level2').remove();
                $('.breadcrumb').append('<span class="level2 black"> / ' + self.attr('data-title') + '</span>');
            }

        // Rig any genre displays
        $('#genreContainer .dynamic').find(".genre").each( function(){
            new Genre(this);
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML and possibly create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Could you post this html fragment: `#all_genres`. If a sub-genre is clicked, the code in the if block to append the Genre is never called.

Answer (score 0):

.html() removes everything in the div and writes new content to the recieving div.

. Append adds to the content.

So use append() or preprend() instead of HTML()